# Kaa Project - Create Schemas

Tags: kaa

I follwing the step from https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

First error occur from step "Create schemas" when I upload and add my schemas like this...

[image]

Then I rename "Namespace" from [ org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.sample ] 
to [ org.kaaproject.kaa.sample ]

And it work no error

Question: Should I do that? I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That happends because 'Your first Kaa application' resembles the Data Collection sample application which is already in the Sandbox. Thus, the name is already there.

You should either use the existing schema or create another with a different name (what you actually did to make it work).